# xl.XmlMap not a valid context C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm working on a project that requires me to import an xml File that will be recreated every day, by multiple People. I'm trying to use [wb.xmlImport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836452.aspx)

but when  I put in in there I get an exception that says "Error 1   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XmlMap' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context" I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

here is my code:

```
private void btnImport_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    xlApp = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application;
    ThisWorkbook wb = Globals.ThisWorkbook;
    deleteDataSheet(wb);

    try
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        xl.Worksheet ws = wb.Sheets["Data"];
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        string path = dialog.FileName.ToString();
        wb.XmlImport(path, out xl.XmlMap, Type.Missing, ws.Range["A1"]);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

    }
```

Comment: You need to pass an instance of type `xl.XmlMap` instead of the type itself. Declare the map separately and pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been an answer not a comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an instance of type xl.XmlMap instead of the type itself. Declare the map separately and pass it as a parameter.

```
    xl.XmlMap map;
    wb.XmlImport(path, out map, Type.Missing, ws.Range["A1"]);
```